# i want to send email with attachments using phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

i am using phpmailler for sending mail,mail works successfully but without attachments. i want to send mail with attachments.
i have tried this code.

thanks in advance.

```
$s2="select * from tbl_new_user where login_name='".$rw['clientname']."'";
$q2=mysql_query($s2) or die($s2);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q2);

$s22="select * from tbl_job_schedule where clientname='".$rw['clientname']."' and jobdate='".$_SESSION['strmonth']."-".$_REQUEST['dt']."-".$_SESSION['yy']."'";
$q22=mysql_query($s22) or die($s22);
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($q22);  

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = '80';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$mail->From = 'abc@abc.com';
$mail->FromName = 'abc@abc.com';
$mail->AddAddress($row['client_email'], '');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress($row['client_email2']);     // Name is optional
$mail->AddAddress($row['client_email3']);
$mail->AddAddress($row['client_email4']);
$mail->AddAddress($row['client_email5']);
$mail->AddAddress($row['client_email6']);
$mail->AddReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->AddCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->AddBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;      
                           // Set word wrap to 50 characters
if($row2['file1']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file1'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file2']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file2'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file3']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file3'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file4']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file4'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file5']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file5'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file6']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file6'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file7']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file7'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file8']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file8'].'');         // Add attachments
}

if($row2['file9']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file9'].'');         // Add attachments
}
if($row2['file10']!='')
{                          
$mail->AddAttachment('kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file10'].'');         // Add attachments
}



//$mail->AddAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Reporting';
$mail->Body    = '<p>This is an automated email report for the work done today.

Below are the comments showing on what we have worked,if you have any questions please go to the reporting URL provided and update your comment or can send a separate email to me directly on my email ID provided.</p>


<b>Work Comments : "'.$row2['client_cmnt'].'"</b>';
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

            echo "<script>window.close()</script>";

}
```

Comment: are you getting any error. And you are attaching too many files

Comment: What is the problem you're having with that code?

Comment: Code looks valid; probably $row2 doesn't contain any values or kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file1'] doesn't results in a valid path (try debugging the content of the $row2 etc)

Comment: no i dont get any error mail sent successfully but without attachments ..maximum attachments may be 10.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the path your are using for your attachments is valid.

i.e. does a file exist at `kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file3']` ?

It might be as simple as you missing a `/` from the beginning to indicate it should start searching from the root directory. If in doubt, try an absolute link to confirm:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/kurtacompany/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file3']`

Comment: $mail->AddAttachment('http://www.kurtacompany.com/techreporting/upload/'.$row2['file1'].'');     
i have tried this path but still i cant find any attachments in my mail

Comment: Make sure you include `http://` before `kurtacompany.com` in your link. As it stands, it will be looking for a folder called 'kurtacompany.com' inside the folder containing your phpmailer handling script. Make it look like: `$mail->AddAttachment('http://kurtacompany.com/techreporting/upload/…);`

Comment: But based on your link there, I would expect that the following relative link would also work (notice the `/` at the beginning which symbolises the root directory): `$mail->AddAttachment('/techreporting/upload/…);`